# I made a multi step slide to buy a product (now I want to link it with woocommerce)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, elementor, woocommerce-subscriptions

I made a multi step slide. In this multi-step slide you can select what you would like to have in your subscription package. If you have checked everything you can enter your details. This is now made with elementor but I would like to add a woocommerce subscription to this. Is there a plugin for how I can handle this? I have already set up the woocommerce subscriptions plugin with a variable product (subscription)

This is how it looks now + variable:
[image: This is how it looks now]

[image: product single page]

This is my live page and how i want it but dont know where to begin:

[image: my live website]

The link of the live webpage [click here](https://wp-roots.nl/aanmelden-2/)
here you can see what im trying to make and what i made for now.
does anybody know how to relize this